# Try to use sklearn library in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pyspark, apache-kafka

I want to apply the label encoder function of sklearn.preprocessing on streaming data using Kafka and Spark structured streaming. So far the idea is:

When I receive a batch of data from the Kafka source each time, I want to implement a function on that batch as follows:

```
def use_label_encoder(label_encoder, y):
   return label_encoder.transform(y) + 1

to_transform_class_val = udf(use_label_encoder, IntegerType())
```

Here is the schema:

```
schema = StructType([
StructField("sepal_length_in_cm", StringType()), \
StructField("sepal_width_in_cm", StringType()), \
StructField("petal_length_in_cm", StringType()), \
StructField("petal_width_in_cm", StringType()), \
StructField("class", StringType())
])

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
df1 = df.select(from_json(df.value, schema).alias("json"))
```

when I try to defined label_encoder:

```
label_encoder = enc.fit(df1.select(to_upper("json.class")))
```

It gives an error "bad input shape"

The equivalent code I used for non-streaming data is:

```
y = df['class'].values
enc = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder = enc.fit(y)
y = label_encoder.transform(y) + 1
```

Could anyone please help me on how to apply sklearn method on streaming data?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add 1 later? Your spark code would become

```
def use_label_encoder(label_encoder, y):
    return label_encoder.transform(y)

to_transform_class_val = udf(use_label_encoder, IntegerType())

df = df.withColumn('new_col', to_transform_class_val(label_encoder, 'old_column'))
df = df.withColumn('label_enc', col('new_col') + lit(1))
```

Comment: use_label_encoder method has 2 arguments but you pass only one when invoke the method

Comment: Missed out on that.. Rectified in the answer.

Comment: But I can not define the label encoder itself. extract from the question: when I try to defined label_encoder:

label_encoder = enc.fit(df1.select(to_upper("json.class")))
It gives an error "bad input shape"